# Ubuntu 21.04 boot problem : "could not create file : out of ressources"

Tags: boot, grub2

For the last couple of days, everytime I boot, I have this error message :

`could not create file: out of ressources`

After 10 seconds, the computer eventually boots normally. So it's more an annoyance than a real problem, but I would like to have it go away (or at least, understand the underlying problem).

The system is all up to date.

NOTE : I have seen posts about "Could not create MOKlistXRT: Out of resources", but since in my case the file isn't specified, I'm not sure if the problem is similar. Therefore, I'd rather not go and tinker inside GRUB if I'm not 100% sure I won't cause more problems!!

Comment: It doesn't have a number in front of it?

Comment: @JoepieEs No. There's only this generic message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE : Upgrading the os to Ubuntu 21.10 has solved the problem.